# Several For-loops optmitization in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, optimization

I'm looking for a better (a.k.a. faster) way of doing 7 for-loops responsible for importing data from an old version of my application into the new version, providing some adaptations. The loops go over 7 different `DataTable`, passing through each `Row` and using the values in its columns for creating a new `TreeItem` element. Each `DataTable` could hold up to 1,5k entries (or `Rows`).

The logic works as follows:

- The first loop is responsible for creating the root elements of the tree, so it must be executed before the rest.
- As for the other 6, on each iteration it will check if the `DataRow` contains valid information to add into the corresponding `TreeItem` previously created.
- As I need to check whether the `TreeItem` have been added on the first `for-loop`, I created a `Dictionary<string, customType>`that would store every added item and its name. Later, I simply use a `if-statement` with a `.ContainsKey` condition.

What I need is optimize this operation, because right now it is taking too long to complete. Bare in mind that not just code optimization would help, but any ideas of how to apply the same logic and get the same results in a different way would be appreciated too. I'd rather change this part of the code than change the Add operations, for example. I'll leave some code snippets, not sure if they will be helpful tho.

```
 private bool ImportItems()
        {
            #region Builds up the structure of the old OptProcess data

            //...Creates DataSets, DataTables and Columns

            #endregion

            try
            {
                //get all the old data from the file
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + exc.ToString());
                Trace.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + " ");
                return false;
            }

            //create a dictionary containing the imported items and its name
            Dictionary<string, customType> AllImportedItems = new Dictionary<string, customType>();

            for (int i = 0; i < tableRoots.Rows.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (tableRoots.Rows[i] != null)
                {
                    DataRow r = tableRoots.Rows[i];

                    //...Do some operations and add the item

                    //add it to the list, alongside its original name
                    AllImportedItems.Add(name, item);
                }          
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < table2.Rows.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (table2.Rows[i] != null)
                {
                    DataRow r_child = table2.Rows[i];
                    if (AllImportedItems.ContainsKey((string)r_child["Name"]))
                    {
                        //...Do some operations and Add the item
                    }
                }
            }

            //Other 5 for loops similar to the previous one goes on here...
            //...

            return true;
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

For better or worse, I'll try to give a better explanation of the "import" process:

- In the previous version of the application, I click on "Export items", which creates an .inf file that is basically a .xml file filled with information about all the existing items.
- Then, on the new version of the app, I click "Import items", choose the .inf file, use the `.ReadXml(pathofthefile)` and then passes all these information to the DataSets, so I can then grab these information as I need and store them on the new format, properly assign it to the new items fields.

Comment: Put your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), they'll help you out.

Comment: Ah.. good old DataTables. I remember battling with these before. Feel free to hop over to CR, but make sure you post *all* of your code (not "Do some operations") otherwise your topic will be closed as off-topic due to being example code.

Comment: Unless there are some other constraints, it's almost always easier to write an SSIS package (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) to transform data from one format to another.

Comment: I would start by refactoring this method as it is fairly large so it is more readable, you could extract part of this into another method that takes a datable and do the loop within here, then you can work on optimizing the operations.  You can also use Datatable.AsEnumerable an implement LINQ to manipulate its data.

Comment: You would also gain a large performance increase by transforming your operations to use LINQ. Written correctly, you would only have to perform one iteration of your data set, which would be a huge speed-up already. In my first bit of professional work, I transformed something that used DataTables to LINQ and ended up going from 2 minutes+ for 10000 rows to nearly instant

Comment: Instead of reading anwfull datatables just query the DB

Comment: You could create a list of datarows like this:
    List<DataRow> AllImportedItems = new List<DataRow>();
Then use Linq to add the whole row to your list
    AllImportedItems = tableRoots.AsEnumerable().OfType<DataRow>().ToList(); I think, instead of adding each one in the for loop

Comment: I think you can also use linq to check if there is a name, something like   tableRoots.AsEnumerable().OfType<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") != null);

Comment: Thank you for all good answers, I'll check them out and try to come up with a solution, maybe combining your techniques.

Comment: @DavidBeaumont I'm not sure if I was very clear, but the dictionary I created to hold the imported items is for checking the conditions of the other loops only. The add operation I was refering to is not adding to this list, but creating a new item based on the information I collected. This operations occur on other layer of the application.

Comment: @CoryNelson I'll definitely check it out, cheers.

Comment: @DrewB I'm not sure of what I'm going to say, but I suspect this approach is either as the saying goes, "killing an ant with a canoon", or isn't even applicable to my situation. I've updated my post with a better (attempt of) explanation of the import process.

Comment: @ARedHerring I was using LINQ to query the list of all imported items, but then I came up with the dictionary approach that seemed to be wiser. But replacing the for loops for a LINQ operations, I cannot think of any way of doing so. Could you share with us your solution for your problem? Maybe it helps to come with an out-of-the-box idea.

Comment: @jean I can't do that, as the info isn't store in a DB, but in a file structured in xml.

Comment: Divide and conquer: first, separate your layers of concerns. Take the code that reads from the data tables, and make it build up a meta structure of data points that will represent the final `Tree`. Then write code that takes this meta structure and creates a brand new `Tree` (or updates, whatever your need). Optimization areas: the code that reads from the data table & builds the tree could possibly be multi-threaded to speed things up dramatically, even taking into consideration a potential need to lock the meta structure.

Comment: @code4life I was thinking of it myself. I just didn't do it yet because I'm totally inexperienced with using threads. But it seems a good approach, I guess...